# qsTr does not work in QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtranslate, qquickview

I use QQuickView to show qml interface in widget application

```
  m_window = new QQuickView();
  m_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(m_window,hostWidget,Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  m_container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
  m_window->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
  m_window->setSource(file_url);
```

I need to make qml interface multilingual, so before instantiating QQuickView i install new translator to application:

```
  m_qmlTranslator = new QTranslator(this); // this - host QWidget    
  m_qmlTranslator->load(QString::fromUtf8("translate_%1").arg(QLocale::system().name()),strTranslationDir);
  QScopedPointer<QCoreApplication> pAppl(QApplication::instance());
  pAppl->installTranslator(m_qmlTranslator);
```

both **load** and **installTranslator** functions returns true. (Translations for target language exists in ts-file and compiled to qm-file which placed to right dir)

Problem is that in C++ translations work well, following code ouputs string in target language

```
   qDebug() << tr("translation test");
```

but in qml interface diplayed by QQuickView string stays untraslated

```
Text {
    id: title
    text: qsTr("translation test")
    font.pixelSize: 36
    font.bold: true
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
}
```

while debugging i found out that `QCoreApplication::translate` function is called by Qt for `qsTr("translation test")` with correct *sourceText* variable, but all QTranslators from `self->d_func()->translators` returns null *QStrings* so visible text stays untranslated.

Any thoughts why this happens and how to make text to be translated in QQuickView?

Comment: Replace this: `QScopedPointer<QCoreApplication> pAppl(QApplication::instance());
  pAppl->installTranslator(m_qmlTranslator);` with this: `qApp->installTranslator(m_qmlTranslator); `

Comment: I tried many ways including qApp->installTranslator. All of them did not lead to correct result - qsTr ("") stays untraslated.

Comment: Are you sure you have translate qml sources? `"translation test"` inside c++ and inside qml filea are different strings.

Comment: @Evgeny - you absolutely right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Evgeny Consider converter your comment to an answer or the OP may do it himself.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had that problem too C++ Translations would work, QML Translations would not (QT 5.12.8). And it cost me maaaaaaany hours to find a solution.

For qml files I used a resource.qrc file. And I named my QML-Files differently. So instead of status.qml I gave them an alias as statusQML.

```
this->pStatus->load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/statusQML")));
```

This did not work. The solution: Taking away the **Alias** in the resource-file and opening like that:

```
this->pStatus->load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/status.qml")));
```

Voilà.

Hopefully this will spare someone some hours. I guess this might be a QT-Bug.